# Putty Automation using TOSCA

Tags: automation, putty, tosca

I am using TOSCA for automating putty. I want to enter commands using TOSCA and want to verify search results too. If there is anyone who has worked on it, please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Tricentis Tosca provides an on-demand Putty Engine as part of the Tosca Classic Engines. You can reach out to [support.tricentis.com](https://support.tricentis.com) to know more about this engine.

Answer (score 0):

Tosca provides an inbuilt standard modules to run a Program use that and in arguments add the server name username, password and use t-box window operation using Regex for the title if you have multiple serves for putty. Regex should be for Tittle.

Answer (score 0):

The "Putty Engine" exists but It's not the greatest. We automated a program that utilized putty and primary used SendKeys commands and Image Verifications

https://documentation.tricentis.com/tosca/1210/en/content/tbox/special_characters.htm
https://documentation.tricentis.com/en/1110/content/tbox/optical_intelligence_generic.htm

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.